# Reading datagridview

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I populated a datagridview from a datatable. How do I read from the datagridview when the application is running?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I populated a datagridview from a datatable. If I change a cell when the application is running I would like to read the altered datagridview in its entirety and write it to a file. I am stuck on the proper way to access the info.

Comment: Re-tag please.  This is not a C#-specific question.  Tag with ".net" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how did you populate it? is the DataSource something useful like a BindlingList? 
If it is then something like:

```
BindingSource bindingSource = this.dataGridView1.DataSource as BindingSource;
//substitute your business object type for T 
T entity = bindingSource.Current as T;
```

would get you the entity bound to the row.

Otherwise there is always the datagridview.Columns[n].Cells[n].Value but really I'd look at using the objects in the DataSource

Edit: Ah... a datatable... righto:

```
 var table = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

 foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
 {
     foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your datagridview and retrieve each cell.

```
for(int i =0; i < DataGridView.Rows.Count; i++){
  DataGridView.Rows.Columns["columnName"].Text= "";
}
```

There is an example [here](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=276684&SiteID=1).

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static DataTable objDataTable = new DataTable("UpdateAddress");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stream myStream = null;
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                    {
                        string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                        List<string> dataFile = new List<string>();
                        dataFile = ReadList(fileName);
                        foreach (string item in dataFile)
                        {
                            string[] temp = item.Split(',');
                            DataRow objDR = objDataTable.NewRow();
                            objDR["EmployeeID"] = temp[0].ToString();
                            objDR["Street"] = temp[1].ToString();
                            objDR["POBox"] = temp[2].ToString();
                            objDR["City"] = temp[3].ToString();
                            objDR["State"] = temp[4].ToString();
                            objDR["Zip"] = temp[5].ToString();
                            objDR["Country"] = temp[6].ToString();
                            objDataTable.Rows.Add(objDR);

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        public static List<string> ReadList(string filename)
        {
            List<string> fileData = new List<string>();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                fileData.Add(sr.ReadLine());
            return fileData;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            objDataTable.Columns.Add("EmployeeID", typeof(int));
            objDataTable.Columns.Add("Street", typeof(string));
            objDataTable.Columns.Add("POBox", typeof(string));
            objDataTable.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
            objDataTable.Columns.Add("State", typeof(string));
            objDataTable.Columns.Add("Zip", typeof(string));
            objDataTable.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
            objDataTable.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));

            dataGridView1.DataSource = objDataTable;
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Displays a SaveFileDialog so the user can save the backup of AD address before the update
            // assigned to Button2.
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "BAK Files|*.BAK";
            saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save AD Backup";
            saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
            {
                TextWriter fileOut = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName); 
                //This is where I want read from the datagridview the EmployeeID column and use it in my BackupAddress method.
            }

        }
```

Comment: Probably would have been better to edit the question rather than posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [DataTable.WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml.aspx), and it's brother [DataTable.ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml.aspx). No fuss, no muss saving of a DataTable.